# Regex to allow special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that will allow alphabets, hyphen (-), quote ('), dot (.), comma(,) and space. this is what i have now

```
^[A-Za-z\s\-]$
```

Thanks

Comment: What's preventing you to add the other permitted characters ? Did you have a problem ?

Comment: Add a dot, quote and comma to the character class then? I believe you're missing the quantifier as well.

Comment: This had nothing to do **specifically** with Javascript...

Comment: @Neal: But the language is relevant, it might support different regex features or need special escaping. Please don't just remove it

Comment: @Neal language tags should be included with the Regex tag. Not neccessary here, but...

Comment: @FabrícioMatté like ^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\"\,]$ but this is giving me an invalid range in character class error

Comment: @rr87: How are you constructing the regex?

Comment: Perhaps JS is different, but in all other regex styles I know the `-` needs to be the first or last character (otherwise it's interpreted as a range) and none of those need to be escaped.

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\"\,]$/.test('a')` works fine, as I've said in my first comment, you're missing the quantifier (e.g. `+` for one or more chars). Also, escaping the dot, comma and quotes is unnecessary. It is also unnecessary to escape `-` if you strategically put it as the first or last char of the char class. So `/^[A-Za-z\s.'",-]+$/.test('a-\'" \t\n\rZ') //true`

Comment: @Bergi i tried both ^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\,]$ & ^[A-Za-z\s\-.',]$ both give me the same error..invalid range in character class

Comment: @FabrícioMatté i have a character limitation and also unicode valuesfor foreign characters ^[A-Za-z\s\xA6\xA8\xAA\xB4\xB5\xB8\xBA\xBC-\xBE\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF\-]{1,25}$ is my complete regex works fine except when i do ^[A-Za-z\s\xA6\xA8\xAA\xB4\xB5\xB8\xBA\xBC-\xBE\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\xFF\-.',]{1,25}$ gives me the error i mentioned

Comment: @rr87: See my answer. If that's not the case, please show us your exact JS code and not just the generic regex part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably tried `new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\"\,]$")`. Yet, you have a string literal there, and the backslashes just escape the following characters - necessary only for the delimiting quote (and for backslashes).

```
"^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\"\,]$" === "^[A-Za-zs-.'\",]$" === '^[A-Za-zs-.\'",]$'
```

Yet, the range `s-.` *is* invalid. So you would need to escape the backslash to pass a string with a backslash in the RegExp constructor:

```
new RegExp("^[A-Za-z\\s\\-\\.\\'\\\"\\,]$")
```

Instead, [regex literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) are easier to read and write as you do not need to string-escape regex escape characters. Also, they are parsed only once during script "compilation" - nothing needs to be executed each time you the line is evaluated. The [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) only needs to be used if you want to build regexes dynamically. So use

```
/^[A-Za-z\s\-\.\'\"\,]$/
```

and it will work. Also, you don't need to escape any of these chars in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - so it's just

```
/^[A-Za-z\s\-.'",]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `\s` from your regex since you said space, and not white space.  Feel free to put it back by replacing the space at the end with `\s` Otherwise pretty simple:

```
 ^[A-Za-z\-'., ]+$
```

It matches start of the string.  Any character in the set 1 or more times, and end of the string.  You don't have to escape `.` in a set, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, try the following:

```
^[A-Za-z\s\-'.,]+$
```

Note that I assumed that you want to match strings that contain one or more of any of these characters, so I added `+` after the character class which mean "repeat the previous element one or more times".

Note that this will currently also allow tabs and line breaks in addition to spaces because `\s` will match any whitespace character.  If you only want to allow spaces, change it to `^[A-Za-z \-'.,]+$` (just replaced `\s` with a space).